# Cursor rect on top of NSTextView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I have implemented an iOS style NSScrollView by adding a knob subview to the NSScrollView. The implementation works just fine except for one thing - the cursor change over the knob view.

I am using `NSView`s `-resetCursorRects` method to setup the cursor rectangle.

```
- (void)resetCursorRects {
  [self addCursorRect:self.knobFrame cursor:[NSCursor pointingHandCursor]];
}
```

This works too, but the Cursor is immediately reset to the `IBeam` style as soon as I cross the cursor rect boundary.

How can I prevent this? Has it something to do with the knob view not being opaque?

UPDATE 0:

---

I also tried to implement it with a normal `NSScroller` and forcing the scroller to overlay the `NSClipView` in the scroll view's `-tile` method, but it seems regardless of what view is placed on top of the `NSTextView` it always enforces the `IBeam` cursor type.

UPDATE 1:

---

I found this [mailing list](http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2010/Mar/msg00699.html) entry that suggests overriding the `NSTextView`s `-mouseMoved`, but since this is not a satisfying solution for a robust custom `NSScrollView` implementation its not really an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting up an `NSTrackingArea` in the `NSScroller` with the `NSTrackingMouseMoved` option set and implementing

```
- (void)mouseMoved:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
  [[NSCursor pointingHandCursor] set];
}
```

does the trick.